# How can I present a one-liner command in Linux to do these things?

Tags: json, linux, http, curl

- A HTTP POST request to an URL using CURL
- Receive the answer in JSON format
- Print the value of the field 'origin' in  the response

I'm lost here, I'd love some help/information sources to study more about these topics

Thanks in advance, and apologies for my English

Comment: Pipe the output of `curl` to `jq`.

Comment: BTW, your English is fine. But you have to do some research and make an honest attempt to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: Probably i didn't Express myself well enough, im looking for some website or source to study the topics needed to solve these questions, not the answer itself. But thanks for your honesty and the quick response Barmar!

Comment: Start Simply with what Barmar said. How do you use `Curl`. Literally, google "How to use curl". Then google "how to use jq". Once you have an understanding of these two you'll be in good hands and will be able to pipe the two commands together to get your result. Your end result will be something like this: `curl XXX | jq YYY`